# How do seperate place DataStores work in roblox?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox, datastore

Lets say, for starters, i have a game. And in that game, I add a few places. If i were to create a datastore in the main GAME, would that transfer to all of the places automatically as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all subsidiary places created under the same game share datastores of the main game. If you want to send specific data to a certain place, use https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TeleportService/GetLocalPlayerTeleportData.

Keep in mind that data sent along with teleports is local and can be manipulated by the client.